# Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number

Tags: android, android-room

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

I know that I can fix this issue by increasing the version number.

I m working in a project which has lots and lots of Database works. There is a chance that I may need to change the database structure at least 50 times a day. So daily I have to increase the number by 50 or more.

If I miss to increase(if by chance) I get the above error.

I have tried `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()` and `exportSchema = false`
with some suggestion from internet surfing.

Do any of you provide me proper solution for this.

Comment: no , you just need to increase every time or you need to change the database name to reset the version

Comment: One of fixes is to delete an app from the device and reinstall it

Answer (score 9):

Having *.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()* is not a great option, as it may lead to data loss when you perform an actual migration in the future (after releasing it to the world).

Go to App Info -> Storage -> Clear storage. This will clear all the data and solve your problem.

Uninstall and reinstall will help only if you have set android:allowBackup="false" under your manifest. 
I recommend reading the docs regarding this: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/autobackup

*Note: Don't change the schema version number for dev/debug build purposes.*

Comment: This is a good option, and i accept, but this one also consume same effort. I wanna reduce my effort... is there any other option.

Comment: The only other workaround will be deleting your database inside onCreate() of the application class (Make sure you do it only on DEBUG variant). So, on every app startup, your existing database gets deleted. The creation of Room DB happens automatically on the first insert/read operation with the new schema you prescribed.

Comment: As of now i m doing the same... Even more i m not comfortable with. And thanks for your help

Comment: Backup was indeed the issue for me. The database file seemed to have been restored upon reinstall.

Answer (score 2):

I see that almost all the answers to the issue about `.fallbackToDestructiveMigration()`have overlooked an important point.

We not only add ".fallbackToDestructiveMigration()" before build() like this

```
Room.databaseBuilder(context.applicationContext,AppDatabase::class.java,"app_database")
            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
            .build()
```

But also need **upgrade your database version in your code**.like this

```
// before upgrade
@Database(version = 1,entities = [User::class])
// after upgrade
@Database(version = 2,entities = [User::class])
```

Only finish these **two steps** can you solve the following issue.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Room cannot verify the data integrity. Looks like you've changed schema but forgot to update the version number. You can simply fix this by increasing the version number.
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Uninstall and reinstall the application in Emulator or in Mobile... This helped...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. I solved this problem by turning off room impelentations in build gradle and then enabling room again and running the program and it worked

If you don't believe it, try it